# How to ask a person to answer a question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have asked this question and I think a particular person who is a member of StackExchange might have a good answer for it. How can I ask her to see my question?

Comment: could we have a link to the question here? or does that defeat the purpose?

Comment: Oh, was this why you asked me in chat? I'm happy that you wanted me to answer it. Unfortunately I'm not an expert in the language and I don't usually answer anything other than word or idiom requests.

Comment: This is actually a FAQ; it's [documented over on the big Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431/273503).

Answer (score 1):

It's not normally possible to get answers from the particular users you like. But if you are sure said users will appreciate you notifying them of your question, then you may try pinging them in chat (if they participate in chats, that is).

Comment: I think if you ping someone in a chat room, that someone will get pinged even if he/she/they don't frequent the chat rooms

Comment: @Clare Nope. There is a time span. If the user hasn't visited chat during that, then they won't be notified.